# Can't able to call .net webservice in android 4.0 it works fine for android 2.3

Tags: android, web-services

I deploy my webservice on web successfull.
I can call it from android 2.3 from my application.
But it not able to call webservice from my app which is running on android 4.0 it gives null error.
I use minimum sdk to API 10

My Code for calling webservice is below

```
                SoapObject request = new SoapObject(NAMESPACE, METHOD_NAME);
                request.addProperty("number", username.getText().toString());
                request.addProperty("password", password.getText().toString());
                SoapSerializationEnvelope envelope = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(
                        SoapEnvelope.VER11);
                envelope.setOutputSoapObject(request);
                envelope.dotNet = true;
                try {
                    Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Wait while connecting server",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    HttpTransportSE androidHttpTransport = new HttpTransportSE(
                            URL);
                    androidHttpTransport.call(SOAP_ACTION, envelope);
                    SoapObject result = (SoapObject) envelope.bodyIn;
                    txt.setText("upto result");
                    if (result != null) {
                        String h = String.valueOf(result.getProperty(0));
                        txt.setText(h);
                        if (h.equalsIgnoreCase("true")) {
                            Intent myIntent = new Intent(getBaseContext(),
                                    ContactList.class);
                            myIntent.putExtra("mobileNumber", username
                                    .getText().toString());
                            startActivity(myIntent);
                        } else {
                            Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Not register or invalid password",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                            txt.setText("Invalid Credential");
                        }
                    } else {
                        txt.setText("Error while connecting server");
                    }
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                    txt.setText("Check internet connection" + e.getMessage());

                }
```

[You Can Download my app from here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/p7oxoodn7591uea/WebConst.apk)

What is the error in my code.

Thanks in advance

Comment: which line it gives 'null error'? show us a logcat

Comment: look like the case of `android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException` read this http://stackoverflow.com/a/6343299/1436931

Comment: 1. Read your logcat; 2. Google the Exception; 3. Search Stackoverflow; 4. Post a question here; including logcat. 99% of the questions don't make it past step 3.

Comment: It give no exception it give error 'null'

Comment: @Nezam `androidHttpTransport.call(SOAP_ACTION, envelope);` This line give me error 'null' and also i am printing error to the TextView if you have Android device 4.0 then please download app from above link and install  @Naeem I not getting any exception like `android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException` Please read the question carefully it works on android device running on 2.3 but not on 4.0 or later

Comment: @SagarChavan `it works on android device running on 2.3 but not on 4.0 ` it is defiantly `NetworkOnMainThread` problem. move your network request in separate thread.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This may be related to the fact that in API 11 and above accessing the net in Main thread is not allowed you may have to use `AsyncTask`.

Embed your code block in an `AsyncTask`, that should solve it.